# Authorizing someone else for in-person passport renewal

Tags: passports, us-citizens

I need my US passport renewed in the next two weeks, but I'm unable to make it in person to a passport office. If I send my documents to a family member, can they apply for an expedited renewal in-person on my behalf?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Get a Passport in a Hurry](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/services/expedited.html):

> Note: If you are a first time applicant, or if your most recent passport is lost or stolen or was issued more than 15 years ago, you must submit a Form DS-11 and apply in person at an authorized passport acceptance facility.

If you must apply in person (for the above reasons), then you must sign the form in the presence of the Acceptance Agent. From [First Time Applicants](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/new.html):

> Please note that you:
>
> - Must not sign the application until instructed to do so by the Acceptance Agent.

Comment: This makes sense. Any insight into whether my presence is required if I want to register in person for a reason _other_ than the ones specified? Namely, I need the renewal expedited, but I am not a first-time applicant nor has my last passport been lost or stolen.

Comment: Well I don't know anything other than what I read there, but it seems like you should be able to apply for expedited service by mail.